# java.lang.NullPointerException error trying to fill arrays

Tags: java, arrays, nullpointerexception

I am trying to put the values (integers) from the 2 dimensional array prices[][] into the cost variable of the objects in the array seatArray[][]. I think the problem is that I am trying to put the values from the prices array into nothing because the seatArray array is only full of object references to null. How would I go about fixing this?

line that calls constructor:

```
        SeatChart seatArray = new SeatChart(givenArray);
```

constructor method:

```
public SeatChart(int[][] prices)
{
    Seat[][] seatArray = new Seat[9][10];
    for(int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
    {   
        for(int j = 0; j < 10; j++)
        {
            seatArray[i][j].cost=prices[i][j];
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
Seat[][] seatArray = new Seat[9][10];
```

This just declares the array and doesn't initialize the array elements with `Seat` objects.

```
for(int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
{   
    for(int j = 0; j < 10; j++)
    {
        // I've used a default Seat() constructor to create the object, in your actual case, it may differ.
        seatArray[i][j] = new Seat(); // Initializing each array element with a new Seat object
        seatArray[i][j].cost=prices[i][j];
    }
}
```

Comment: That solved the compiling error! But now when I run my program, there is still a nullpointer error. (It happens whenever it has to refer to the objects in the array.) Do you know why this is? (I still don't think the objects are still not being initialized somehow.)

Comment: That's what. You need to create a new Seat object and assign it to each element of the array.

Comment: It still isn't working. I have that exact code, but I still keep getting a nullpointer exception (but in runtime now). I get the problem when I run code that involves accessing the objects of the array.

Comment: I don't see where it would throw an NPE now. Can you post some more code and where exactly is the error being thrown?

Comment: I'm having trouble formatting code in the commments. Is there a way to do blocks of code in the comments?

Comment: You have 2 variables with the same name `seatArray`. One is an instance of `SeatChart` and the other is an `array of Seat`. Which one are you referring to?

Comment: The instance of SeatChart should be an array of seats. I do use the same name (seatArray) in my SeatingTest class and my SeatChart class, though, so that may be the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
seatArray[i][j] = new Seat();
seatArray[i][j].cost= prices[i][j];
```

Or maybe for clarity

```
Seat seat = new Seat();
seat.setCost(prices[i][j]);
seatArray[i][j] = seat;
```